# How does Windows bootloader add option to open firmware setup?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, firmware, assembly

There is an option in Windows Setup<sup>1</sup> which lets one enter firmware setup<sup>2</sup>. How does it do it? I would guess it would be some kind of assembly instruction, but I'm not sure which it is.

<sup>1</sup> If my memory serves me right.
<sup>2</sup> After perhaps a reboot...

Comment: That isn’t very nice. **The close reason is a reason.**

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, I see it there. So some monkey decided that this is "primarily opinion based". Wow, that's intelligent.

Comment: Which version of Windows? Are you referring to "UEFI Firmware Settings"? Can you add some more details to the question?

Comment: I disagree with the 3 "unclear" close votes because this question has an accepted answer that was also awarded a bounty. That doesn't really satisfy the requirements for an unclear close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UEFI firmwares with Fast Boot support the `OsIndications` EFI variable which contains a 64-bit bitmask. To request the firmware settings interface, Windows sets bit 1 in this variable (also known as EFI_OS_INDICATIONS_BOOT_TO_FW_UI), followed by a normal system reboot.

- UEFI Spec – OsIndications variable format:
  https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf#page=345
- Intel devblog:
  https://firmware.intel.com/blog/using-os-indications-uefi
- Systemd implementation on Linux:
  https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2013-January/008216.html

Booting into other OS entries is implemented using the `BootNext` EFI variable, which is a 16-bit integer containing the number of the desired `Boot####` entry. For example, the OS can set it to 0x0002 followed by a regular reboot, for Boot0002 to be used.

Both variables are automatically cleared by firmware after they've been consumed once.

- UEFI Spec – BootNext variable format:
  https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf#page=156
- UEFI Spec – information for the whole boot process:
  https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf#page=143

In both cases, the variables are set by calling the `SetVariable()` method on EFI Runtime Services. This is not accessible to userspace code directly, but you can use OS-provided APIs to do the same thing. (On Windows you can use [SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfirmwareenvironmentvariablew), on Linux `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` or libefivar.)

Comment: I get the option with "BIOS boot" (legacy boot on a UEFI machine) as well... Would you have any guesses how *that* is done?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer!

Comment: No, I have no idea. It might be a BIOS interrupt (not INT 21h – that's a DOS interrupt and Windows NT series does not use DOS) but I can't find anything like that on any lists.

Comment: [This forum thread](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/94265-create-shortcut-boot-uefi-firmware-settings-windows-10-a-2.html) says Windows doesn't actually support it on BIOS systems. I don't know if the installer might use some other trickery, but apparently on regular installed systems it is not an option. (I don't think I have any non-UEFI machines to actually test it on.)

Comment: I may have been mis-remembering then. Thank you for putting so much effort :).

Comment: Sadly, the intel firmware blog is dead and has been for at least a month or so. I have been able to find some old posts on the Wayback Machine, but the post linked in this answer seems to be missing from there _and_ Google's Cache. :(

Comment: The bit being set in the OsIndications EFI variable is in fact bit 0 (the zeroth or least significant bit) with value 1, not bit 1 which would have the value 2.

Answer (score 0):

INT 20 is available at POST performing some of the functions available on INT 21 once the DOS is loaded. I cant recall the exact parameters for the INT 20 call but if you have a search youll find what the al, ah and possibly other registers have to be set to in order to reboot invoking the bios settings screen.

Comment: But on WinNT systems, the DOS is never loaded. If it's a function provided by the BIOS itself, could you actually include the relevant parameters?

Comment: So I opened Ralf Brown's Interrupt List and have some sense of what you're talking about but the question would arise- how is DOS doing it. And then how could it be emulated. I'm looking to use it in GRUB.